# Select and compare two elements from two dataframes using R

Tags: r

I want to calculate the shortest path between two proteins using two dataframes. For example, I want to calculate the shortest path of first from the first list and the first from the seconds list, the first from the first list and the second from the second list, etc.

```
structure(list(LAS1L = c("FKBP4", "RBM6", "UPF1", "SLC25A5", 
"DHX33", "ELAC2", "CCDC124", "RPS20", "CSDE1", "AKAP8L", "UTP18", 
"PTBP1", "DCN", "MATR3", "SAMD4A", "AQR", "STRAP", "SEC63", "BCLAF1", 
"TFB1M", "GRN", "ZCCHC8", "NSUN2", "SKIV2L2", "STAU2", "CTNNA1", 
"YTHDC2", "POLR2B", "TPR", "MAP4", "NOP16", "FAM120A", "R3HDM1", 
"PTCD2", "RRP12", "MRTO4", "THRAP3", "NOP58", "USP36", "MLL3", 
"PUM2", "MRPL43", "ZFR", "RC3H2", "ZC3H11A", "PARP12", "ALDH18A1", 
"CSDA", "CCAR1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -49L
))
```

```
structure(list(GNL3L = c("FMR1", "FRAXA", "UBA1", "CSTF2", "MECP2", 
"PHF6", "RBM10", "GSPT2", "SLC25A5", "EIF1AX", "NKRF", "RPS4X", 
"RBMX2", "HTATSF1", "LAS1L", "MBNL3", "HUWE1", "RPL10", "RPL15", 
"RBMX", "NONO", "RPGR", "UPF3B", "RBM3", "HNRNPH2", "UTP14A", 
"DKC1", "MEX3C", "DDX3X", "FLNA", "FAM120C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-31L))
```

So far, I just come out with this.

```
sp<-shortest_path[protein1[,1],protein2[,1]]
```

dput for shortest_path:

```
structure(c(0, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 0, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 
3, 3, 6, 5, 0, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5, 3, 6, 5, 5, 
5, 4, 4, 6, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 3, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 6, 3, 4, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
5, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 4, 4, 5, 
3, 4, 4, 2, 0, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
2, 2, 2, 4, 0, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 6, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
2, 4, 2, 4, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
4, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 
2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 
5, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 2, 2, 0), .Dim = c(20L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(c("1810055G02Rik", 
"2810046L04Rik", "4922501C03Rik", "4930572J05Rik", "9830001H06Rik", 
"A1CF", "A2M", "AAGAB", "AATF", "ABCA1", "ABCA13", "ABCA2", "ABCA4", 
"ABCB1", "ABCB7", "ABCC2", "ABCC8", "ABCD1", "ABCD3", "ABCD4"
), c("1810055G02Rik", "2810046L04Rik", "4922501C03Rik", "4930572J05Rik", 
"9830001H06Rik", "A1CF", "A2M", "AAGAB", "AATF", "ABCA1", "ABCA13", 
"ABCA2", "ABCA4", "ABCB1", "ABCB7", "ABCC2", "ABCC8", "ABCD1", 
"ABCD3", "ABCD4")))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is shortest path between two proteins? Please provide more information regarding the desired output and how-to.

Comment: I already have the matrix for the path length which is the "shortest_path". My function is shortest_path(x,y) where x is the element in first list while y is the nth element in the second list. Instead of just first to first or second to second, I want first to first, first to second, first to third and etc.

Comment: Okey, then please `dput()` your matrix as well. I will take a look on it with the matrix information.

Comment: Hi, I pulled out 1-20 rows and columns of my matrix :) please have a look.

Comment: I didn't see the relation between the matrix and two dataframes. Could you provide a smaller but consistent example?

Comment: For example in the first list, the first row is FKBP4 while the first row on the second list is FMR1. So these two proteins can be found in the matrix with certain values. It would be the shortest path length.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
outer(protein1$LAS1L, protein2$GNL3L, FUN = function(x, y) shortest_path[x, y])
```